# Why is the Visual Micro serial graph output jagged/lagging?

Tags: visual-studio, plot, arduino, visual-studio-2022, visualmicro

I started using Visual Studio 2022 with Visual Micro, Arduino 1.6/1.8 as my new Arduino IDE, because I needed some extra features, that the original Arduino IDE does not provide.

To plot a graph, I am using the breakpoint command `{@Plot.windowName.graphName variable}` to print out the graph for my variable x with `x = sin(2i)`, `i` being incremented by 0.01 every cycle by a *for* loop.

Here is my code:

```c++
double x;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Hello, World!");
}

void loop() {
    float i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i=i+0.01) {
        x = sin(2*i);
        Serial.println(x);
        delay(50);
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the breakpoint command:

[image: Picture of the breakpoint-command {@Plot.plot.output x}]

The graph this outputs looks jagged and has cyclically occurring lags every 1.5 second.

[image: Sine graph in the serial plotter, with jagged edges instead of a smooth curve]

Where might this originate from?

Is it the Visual Micro software, the speed/noisiness of the serial connection (bad cable, etc.) or the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) being overloaded by that?

I already tried changing the data rates as recommended in [the answer of visualmicro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621355/why-is-the-visualmicro-serial-graph-output-jagged-lagging/71603768#71603768).

Unfortunately it is not about the data rate itself.

Comment: [Mechanism for debug support](https://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Working-With-Breakpoints.html) for Arduino Uno: *"For every breakpoint, Visual Micro "invisibly" adds a few lines of code to your source code. This code represents the breakpoint and performs the communication between the board and your PC. These extra lines of code will not appear in your source files, Visual Micro manages it in the background. However, every breakpoint will consume a few bytes of program memory because of that extra code."*. That is clever!

Comment: And: *"If you want to* ***set/change/delete*** *a breakpoint, then you have to* ***rebuild and upload*** *your Arduino sketch. ... Visual Micro's debugging lets you view and change variables at runtime. However, you must specify the variables you want to watch and modify* ***before*** *you build and upload your sketch."*

Comment: Where is "`{@Plot.windowName.graphName variable}`" located? In the Arduino source code? In Visual Micro? Isn't it "`{@Plot.windowName.graphName x}`"?

Comment: What happens if you make it slower, e.g. 500 ms instead of 50 ms?

Comment: Isn't the "`Serial.println(x);`" line superfluous (and potentially interfering) if you use the Visual Micro mechanism to capture the output? The Visual Micro mechanism also uses the (same) serial port.

Comment: (There is also [a site specifically for Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour). [A site search for "Visual Micro"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=+Visual+Micro) returns 71 results (though with some false positives).)

Comment: From *[Debugging your Arduino Sketch Visual Micro](https://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Debugging.html)*: *"If you use the serial port yourself in your sketch, then make sure that the baud rate* ***set by your code*** *(with Serial.Begin)* ***matches*** the baud rate that Visual Micro uses for debugging."

Answer (score -1):

The Serial Debugger in Visual Micro throttles the data coming from the sketch to prevent the PC becoming overloaded with Serial data.

If you enable the vMicro > Debugger > Full Speed (no throttle), this should speed up the data coming in.

Also the interval the chart refreshes at can be changed from the controls above it, in this scenario "At rate of incoming data" would be best suited.

[image: vMicro Chart Controls (Click for image)]